# Change subnet of Android Emulator?

Tags: android, networking, emulation, subnet

I need to test an App I wrote that's being used in a different country. This app will only work there as it communicates with the local network there. My boss has asked me to remote in and install the Android emulator on the client PC so we can run tests.

The PC's net config operates on the subnet 192.168.0.xx
The devices the app wants to communicate with are on 192.168.1.xx

There doesn't seem to be a way to get the emulator to work on the different subnet. The internet works so I'm assuming this is blindly using the client PCs internet connection (on 192.168.0.xx). In which case if I change the client PC's network configuration I'll lose my remote connection and cannot continue my work!

I've had a Google to no avail.

Any suggestions?
Thanks.